# Show $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}z^n$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Show that the following series converge on $\mathbb{C}$:
>
> $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}z^n$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a variable.

I applied the Abel Dirichlet´s test:

If I choose $|z|<1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}z^n=0$

However my problem lies with $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}$ that I am trying to prove its sum can be majored.
I have tried several tests (root test,ratio test,Weierstrass test). All seem to fail. I noticed  that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}=e^2>1$

However I am supposed to prove $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}z^n$ is convergent.

**Question:**

How should I prove it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^{n^2}=\infty$. Fortunately, that is not the limit that comes up when you apply the root test.

Comment: Numerically, it looks like it converges for $|z|<\frac1{e}$.

Comment: @SteveKass How did you conclude that?

Comment: @Nick Please check the update!

Comment: I evaluated the sum numerically in Mathematica (using the NSum function) for various values of $z$.

Comment: *Definitely*, isn't convergent for all $z$.

Comment: The problem is false as stated. Please edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the root test:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\root n\of{|(1 + 1/n)^{n^2}z^n|} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}{(1 + 1/n)^n}|z| = e|z|
$$
and the series is convergent for $|z| < 1/e$.